# Newtonsoft is not serializing navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, json.net

I have an EF object `RetailDocuments`. It is related to the `DocumentTemplateMaster` object via foreign key. Many `RetailDocuments` can have the same `DocumentTemplateMaster`.

I'm retrieving a `List<RetailDocument>` and have turned off proxy creation and lazy loading. The referenced `DocumentTemplateMaster` object is there in the List but not when it is serialized.

I've tried a number of solutions I've seen here on SO and other places but for whatever reason, it's not working for me.

Here's my code, commented code shows stuff I've tried but didn't seem to make a difference:

```
using (RetailDocumentEntities db = new RetailDocumentEntities()) {
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    List<RetailDocument> retailDocuments =  
    retailDocuments = db.RetailDocument.Include("DocumentTemplateMaster").where(x=>x.col2 = "someVal").ToList();

    JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects };
string retVal = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(retailDocuments, Formatting.Indented, serializerSettings);

    //JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize};// PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects};// ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize, ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize };
    //string retVal = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(retailDocuments, settings);
    return retVal;
}
```

Before I serialize it, `DocumentTemplateMaster` shows up as a navigation property in the List as it should but when serialized, it is missing. I'm sure it's a silly little thing I'm missing but what is it?

Edit: the context is defined and the include is there. The referenced DocumentTemplateMaster is there in the retrieved list. This is not the problem. *The problem is in the serialization as it is not in the serialized string*

Comment: If `db` is new context instance, it *can't* contain a `DocumentTemplateMaster` object after running the code you show. How do you check its existence?

Comment: See updated code. I figured it would be understood that context was defined :/ In any case, in debug mode, I can see the Document TemplateMaster clearly.

Comment: Ah, so you `Include` it, good to know that... You have `PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects`, so you would only see a few `DocumentTemplateMaster`s in the Json. In most places you should see something like `"$ref": "2"`.

Comment: I just found the problem. Navigation properties kind of need the [DataMember] Attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot more research, it would appear that navigation properties also need to have the `[DataMember]` attribute.

Once I added that, the problem went away.

Sometimes it's the simple things.

Comment: in my case I added `[DataMember]` on the navigation property but when i requested the Json result I faced an exception _possible object cycle was detected_  
So, When i want to _include (eager load )_ data how can i do it in order to avoid that error ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your navigation property if you have lazy loading turned off

```
retailDocuments = db.RetailDocument.Include(x => x.DocumentTemplateMaster).where(x=>x.col2 = "someVal").ToList();
```

However note that Include has some notable performance impact. Often it is better to retrieve the values in 2 separate calls and add the relation in memory.

Comment: See update to my code where I've explicitly added the include for you. The actual retrieval method is a custom method we use that automatically puts the include in there. In any case, assuming that I'm actually seeing the DocumentTemplateMaster object in the returned list, the include statement could not possibly be the problem.