# losing inheriting types on the way from asp.net core to Angular

Tags: json, angular, asp.net-core-2.2, ef-core-2.2

I am developing an application with asp.net core 2.2 and ef core 2.2 on the server and Angular 7 on the client side. I am not able to figure this out:

I have the following (simplified) models:

```
public abstract class LegalEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public Address FiscalAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Organisation : LegalEntity
{
    public Organisation(){}
    public Organisation(LegalEntityType legalEntityType, string name, Address fiscalAddress)
    {
        LegalEntityType = legalEntityType;
        Name = name;
    }
    public LegalEntityType LegalEntityType { get; set; }
}


public class LegalEntityType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public LegalEntityType(){}
    public LegalEntityType(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}


public class Person : LegalEntity
{
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public override string Name => string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
}

public class Gender
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Customer(){}
    public Customer(LegalEntity legalEntity)
    {
        LegalEntity = legalEntity;
    }
    public LegalEntity LegalEntity { get; set; }
}
```

When I return Customer Entities to the client through the API somestimes LegalEntity is an Organisation, sometimes a Person. Following which type (Organisation or Person) is returned, I want the property LegalEntityType (in case of Organisation) or the property Gender (in case of Person) to be rendered into the JSON code. This is my first problem, the following leaves them both null:

```
.Include(o => o.Customer).ThenInclude(o => o.LegalEntity)
```

as this does not load the navigation properties that are only present in the inheriting Entities. Here is an extract of the JSON string in case of

Person:

```
...
 "customer": {
            "legalEntity": {
                "gender": null,
                "firstName": "Denis",
                "lastName": "Testmann",
                "name": "Denis Testmann",
                "id": 9
            },
...
```

Organisation:

```
...
 "customer": {
            "legalEntity": {
                "legalEntityType": null,
                "name": "Companyname GmbH",
                "id": 6
            },
...
```

What should come out instead is the following:

Person:

```
...
 "customer": {
            "Person": {
                "gender": null,
                "firstName": "Denis",
                "lastName": "Testmann",
                "name": "Denis Testmann",
                "id": 9
            },
...
```

Organisation:

```
...
 "customer": {
            "Organisation": {
                "legalEntityType": null,
                "name": "Companyname GmbH",
                "id": 6
            },
...
```

To bring it to point: a customer may be a person or an organisation, both Entities (Organisation and Person) inherit from LegalEntity and therefore the customers Property “LegalEntity” sometimes is a Person, sometimes an Organisation. When I render the JSON the specific type has to be maintained.

Hopefully I was clear enough - please excuse me being so long, I want to be sure that the problem is understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok - found the solution !

on the server side, you have to serialize the JSON content with

SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto

what you should do in the Startup.cs file:

```
    services.AddJsonOptions(opt =>
    {
        opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
            Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        opt.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
    })
```

and on the client side you may use class-transformer (https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer).

for my example the customer class - where the LegalEntity might be either of type Person or Organisation looks like this:

```
public class Customer
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }

    @Type( () => Object, {
        discriminator: {
          property: '$type',
          subTypes: [
            {value: Person, name: 'Your.Name.Space.Person, YourApp.Name'},
            {value: Organisation, name: 'Your.Name.Space.Organisation, YourApp.Name'},
          ],
        },
      })
       public LegalEntity LegalEntity { get; set; }
   }
```

and then you build an instance of the customer class from the plain javascript object like that:

```
    import { plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';

    export class SomeClassInYourAngularApp implements OnInit {

customerList: Customer[];

      ngOnInit() {
        this.customerList = new Array<Customer>();
        let u: any;

    // lets get the plain js object form somewhere, ex. from a resolver
        this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
          u = data['customerList'].result;
        });

        u = plainToClass(Customer, u);
        Object.assign(this.customerList, u);
      }
```

that's it !

Answer (score 0):

**New Answer**

I put together the following Program.cs via `dotnet new console` via dotnet core 2.1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<Customer>();
        list.Add(new Customer(new Person { Gender = new Gender{ Name = "Male"}}));
        list.Add(new Customer(new Organisation { LegalEntityType = new LegalEntityType{ Name = "GmbH"}}));
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
    }
}

public abstract class LegalEntity
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual string Name { get; set; }
   public Address FiscalAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Organisation : LegalEntity
{
   public Organisation(){}
   public Organisation(LegalEntityType legalEntityType, string name, Address fiscalAddress)
   {
       LegalEntityType = legalEntityType;
       Name = name;
   }
   public LegalEntityType LegalEntityType { get; set; }
}


public class LegalEntityType
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public LegalEntityType(){}
   public LegalEntityType(string name)
   {
       Name = name;
   }
}

public class Person : LegalEntity
{
   public Gender Gender { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public override string Name => string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
}

public class Gender
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class Customer
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public Customer(){}
   public Customer(LegalEntity legalEntity)
   {
       LegalEntity = legalEntity;
   }
   public LegalEntity LegalEntity { get; set; }
}    

public class Address
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Line1 { get; set; }
   public string Line2 { get; set; }   
}
```

The output appears like this:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 0,
    "LegalEntity": {
      "Gender": {
        "Id": 0,
        "Name": "Male"
      },
      "FirstName": null,
      "LastName": null,
      "Name": " ",
      "Id": 0,
      "FiscalAddress": null
    }
  },
  {
    "Id": 0,
    "LegalEntity": {
      "LegalEntityType": {
        "Id": 0,
        "Name": "GmbH"
      },
      "Id": 0,
      "Name": null,
      "FiscalAddress": null
    }
  }
]
```

This looks ok? Maybe check what serializer settings your API endpoint binder is using.

**Old Answer**

If LegalEntity is real table in the database, you should be able to use:

```
    [ForeignKey("LegalEntity")]
    public int LegalEntityId { get; set; }
```

in your `Customer` definition.

You'll need to set the key as well:

```
    public abstract class LegalEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Name { get; set; }
        public Address FiscalAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

if LegalEntity isn't a real table, then add separate navigations for Person/Organisation

Comment: Hi @user326608 - thanks for your answer. Yes, LegalEntity is a real table (and used by Organisation and Person) but in fact the load from the db is not my problem - this works fine (as I stick to the convention I do not need to use the ForeignKey attribute). My problem is the passing into JSON where the types Person and Organisation get lost. Perhaps I am not clear enough in my question?

Comment: ok so when you debug you can see the related entities, but the json serializer isn't striping them as expected? see if https://stackoverflow.com/a/38529712 helps? it looks like you might need to instruct Json.NET explicitly

Comment: yes and no, the serializer strips the Organisation and the Person Entity both as LegalEntities - and you probably would expect this in some kind as they both inherit from LegalEntity. What I want is to not loose the actual specific type (which is eather Person or Organisation) as LegalEntity is only an abstract. 
I just added some lines of explenation in the second half of my question to make it more clear - hope this helps to undestand my issue. Thanks so much for your kind support.

Comment: see my updated answer, see if you can use the sample program to replicate your issue. i tried using `var legalEntities = list.Select(x => x.LegalEntity).ToList<LegalEntity>();` and still got the same output json

Comment: Hello ! I can replicate the output. I wonder if I have a misconception on how inheriting types are transported in JSON. In your output, too, both Entities (Organisation and Person) are stored in the  subschema LegalEntity. If I want to deserialize them (in my case in Angular, but could be the same in C#), how does the deserializer knows if the LegalEntity is an Organisation or a Person? I would guess that the best would be that the serializer names the subschema either “Organisation” or “Person” instead of “LegalEntity” in both cases. Thanks if you could clarify this to me !